# Conditional probability

Tags: probability-or-statistics, distributions

I am new to *Mathematica*. I am asking how to define a conditinal probability in *Mathematica*.

Here is an example of what I want to do:

Assume that $P(x_b\,|\,x_i)=\left\{
     \begin{array}{}
       1-p & : x_b=0\\
       p & : x_b=x_i 
     \end{array}
   \right.$

where $P(x_b|x_i)$ is the conditional probability which takes 0 with probability of $1-p$ and takes the value of $x_i$ with probability $p$, where $0\le p\le 1$.

Also, we have $x_i\in U[3,5]$, by which I mean $x_i$ is uniformly distributed between 3 and 5.

I know that: $P(x_i,x_b)=P(x_b|x_i)P(x_i)$

I know how to define $P(x_i)$ in *Mathematica* using

```
xi=UniformDestribution[{3,5}]
```

but I want to find how to define conditional probability $P(x_b|x_i)$ in *Mathematica*.
I tried to use the following:

```
xb = TransformedDistribution[xi xb, xb \[Distributed] BernoulliDistribution[p]]
```

and then multiply $x_b$ with $x_i$, but when I run

```
RandomVariate[xb xi]
```

I get error message

> The valid numeric parameters of distribution TransformedDistribution[[FormalX]UniformDistribution[{3,5}], [FormalX][Distributed]BernoulliDistribution[0.1]] are expected. Use DistributionParameterAssumptions to obtain the parameter assumptions.

Is there any way to find $P(x_i,x_b)$ which equals $P(x_b|x_i)P(x_i)$

Comment: Welcome! It is always a good idea to show your previous efforts and code (if available). Have you already searched the online help and this site for relevant threads?

Comment: I tried to find something online, but I couldn't find anything. Also, I tried to find $p(x_i,x_b)$ using ProdutDistribution, but I think this is wrong.

Comment: What about: https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Probability.html ?

Comment: Yeah, I'd checked that. Nothing useful for my problem.

Comment: For all values of $x_i$, $P(1|x_i)>1$ and is not a proper probability.  Are you sure this is what you want?

Comment: It appears that $x_b$ is a binary variable taking values 0 and 1 and that no matter what the value of $x_i$, the probability of $x_b$ is zero.  Further because $x_i$ takes on values between 3 and 5, that those values can't be used for a probability.  So...is this description not constructed properly or am I just totally misunderstanding?

Comment: I've corrected the post

Comment: I think you still have some correcting to do.  $P(x_b|x_i$) can't be a probability function if $x_b$ can take on all real values between 3 and 5.  Do you want $x_b$ to have a uniform distribution on 3 through 5 with probability $p$ and zero with probability $1-p$ ?

Comment: Here is what I want to do, I have $x_b$ Bernoulli distributed with parameter $p$, and takes value of 0 with probability $1-p$, and takes value $x_i$ with probability of $p$. I also have $x_i$ uniformly distributed between 3 and 5, and I want to find $p(x_b,x_i)$.

Comment: You might find `ParameterMixtureDistribution` helpful.

Comment: `ParametricMixtureDistribution` is useful if we can somehow modify `BernoulliDistribution`  to take value other than 1 with probability $p$.

Comment: @AhmedZeki "I have $x_b$ Bernoulli distributed with parameter p".  $x_b$ does not have a Bernoulli distribution.  You can define $x_b=\alpha x_i$ with $\alpha$ having a Bernoulli distribution, however.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The joint density function of $x_b$ and $x_i$ can be written as

```
f[xb_, xi_] := Piecewise[{{(1 - p)/2, xb == 0 && 3 <= xi <= 5}, {p/2, 3 <= xb <= 5 && 3 <= xi <= 5}}]
```

- Added May 12, 2015 *

While I haven't been able to get *Mathematica* to display the joint density function from the `TransformedDistribution` function, that function does supply some of the appropriate characteristics of the joint distribution function:

```
xbxi = TransformedDistribution[{\[Alpha] xi, 
   xi}, {xi \[Distributed] 
    UniformDistribution[{3, 5}], \[Alpha] \[Distributed] 
    BernoulliDistribution[p]}]
Mean[xbxi]
Covariance[xbxi]
RandomVariate[xbxi /. p -> 1/3, 10]
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. This is exactly what I wanted.